# Refreshing form from timer in another form

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, timer

I have a problem with the snippet of the code I have got to extend and improve. It is not my original code and I cannot change the logic that much of it, just to be clear.

I have one main form called MDIServer, which has a timer set for every second. In Timer.Tick I have some other code which works fine (timer is running okay). Newly, I had to check there, if one form is Active and if so, change some stuff (labels text and tags) in that form and refresh it.

I add there this code:

```
If IsActiveForm("frmName") Then
      frmName.ChangeSomething()
End If
```

The Sub ChangeSomething is, how you can see, located in the form I want to refresh and do the changes. In that function I simply change the label text and tags of few controls.

**My question is: Form is not refreshing => labels are not visible changed, why?**

I think I tried already almost anything with Refresh() function in the ChangeSomething() function or in the timer after I called this function. Also I tried to add there new timer (in frmName) and do the changes there, which works perfectly with

```
Label.Text = "something new"
Label.Refresh()
```

So I guess problem is somewhere with the refreshing form from Timer in different form. I also tried to do it with my own InvokeReguired() function etc...

P.S. When I am debugging the code, labels and tags are changing and every single function which has to be called, is called, but it is just not visible on the form itself.

**EDIT Info**
`formName` is not declared in MDIServer explicitely and in this case and many other cases, forms are used as default instances. Timer is from `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`.  Also MDIServer is not a MDIParent of the `formName` and I cannot use `Me.ActiveMdiChild Is`. Lets just say, these two forms are not dependent on each other in any way.. and everything is done through name of the form (default instance, so nothing like `Dim frm As Form` and `frm = frmName`).

I would be really glad for any tip or anything :D

Thanks guys,
Vojta

Comment: how is this VBA?

Comment: And how is this C#?

Comment: Is `frmName` declared in the form MDIServer code?  This sounds like a problem of inadvertently using the VB _Application Framework_ default instance of `frmName` versus the intended reference.  If MDIServer is a MDI parent form, then the usage of `IsActiveForm("frmName")` is setting off alarm-bells as condition should be `Me.ActiveMdiChild Is frmName`.

Comment: @TnTinMn the form is not declared in the form MDIServer and also it is not a parent. So I guess, I need to use reference on that form and with that reference use needed function and refresh? Thank you for the hint.

Comment: Ok, so this is not a MDI form project.  Where is `frmName` declared? Are you confirming that this code is using _default_ form instances?  You state you are using the Timer.Tick event and that implies that the timer a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`; is this correct?  This is important as other timer's tick/elapsed events arrive on a secondary thread and accessing a Default form instance from a secondary thread creates a new instance for that thread.  Please update your question with as much information that you can share.  Right now, I can not decipher how your code in structured.

Comment: @TnTinMn I tried to update somehow information and describe it best I know.. like I said unfortunately this is not my code and I would for sure implemented it little bit differently.. so much pain doing this stuff after someone else... I also tried `frmName.Invalidate()`, but also doesnt work. Thank you for trying to help me man :D

Comment: In which form/module/class do you have your code?
(If IsActiveForm("frmName") Then
      frmName.ChangeSomething()
End If)

Comment: @Zeddy This code I have in form MDIServer, but the SUB `ChangeSomething` is in different form `frmName` and that form I want refresh somehow, after I call this SUB from timer tick in another form....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I fixed my problem after some research and the problem was (expected) that I am not calling the subroutine `ChangeSOmething()` for one specific instance of the form `frmName`. So I had to change my code, that I will call it exactly for the instance which is active and visible.

New code looks like this:

```
Dim frmCollection = Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms
    Dim listfrmname = frmCollection.OfType(Of frmName).ToList()
    If listfrmName.Count > 0 Then
        Dim tmpFrm As frmName = listVZT15.Last()
        tmpFrm.ChangeSomething()
    End If
```

I also could not use combination of `frmCollection.OfType(Of frmName).Any` and `frmCollection.Item("frmName")`, because when I was closing the form and opening again, it created new and new instances (I dont know, why it is not closing the old one, but like I said, it is not my code).  So the logic is, to list all open forms of the needed type, and then take the last instance from that list and for that instance call the subroutine. Also `Me.Refresh()` is placed in the subroutine `ChangeSomething()` itself.

Thanks everyone for help, it surely helped me to understand, how the instances works here.